# ¿Cómo devolver un string en una consulta SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo esta función en PHP que devuelve la descripción de un usuario a partir del id:

```
   public function GetDescripcion($id){
    $sql = $this->link->prepare("SELECT descripcion FROM users WHERE id= :id;");
    $sql->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $results;
}
```

Pero de esta forma me devuelve un array. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva un string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías probar el método `implode`, que une elementos de un array a un **String**, para ello tendrías que substituir la línea `return` de con de tu código por la siguiente. Recuerda que **$cadenaArray** es solo un nombre asignado por mí para el ejemplo.

`return $cadenaArray = implode(",", $results);`

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
$array_equipo = array('portero', 'laterales', 'centrales', 'mediocentros', 'interiores', 'delanteros');
$cadena_equipo = implode(";", $array_equipo);
echo "El equipo separaro por ';' es el siguiente: " .$cadena_equipo;
$cadena_equipo2 = implode($array_equipo);
echo "<br><br>El equipo sin parámetro string es el siguiente: " .$cadena_equipo2;
```

**Explicacion**

Primero creamos el array que contiene las posiciones de un equipo de fútbol.

En un primer ejemplo vamos a crear el string con el delimitador ‘;’, así las posiciones estarán divididas por el punto y coma. Sacamos por pantalla el resultado.

En el segundo ejemplo no pasamos el parámetro delimitador $string, por lo que, al sacar el resultado por pantalla nos salen todos los valores juntos sin separación.
[fuente](http://www.anerbarrena.com/php-implode-4685/)

Comment: Vale, ya he conseguido que me funcione, muchas gracias.